# Looping through an Object containing an Array of Objects in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, object

I have an ajax request which loads a JSON file and parses it by storing a reference to the object. 
I'm trying to find a way in which I can loop through the object but due to it's structure I get errors on the console.

Here is an example of the JSON that I am parsing:

```
{
  "markers": {
    "marker": [
      {
        "name": "john",
        "latitude": "53.4682282",
        "longitude": "-2.238547"
      },
      {
        "name": "david",
        "latitude": "53.4663409",
        "longitude": "-2.2328164"
      },
      {
        "name": "mathew",
        "latitude": "53.4668135",
        "longitude": "-2.2310998"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried the following js loop, but I can't seem to get it to work correctly. (N.B. the object retrieved from parsing the JSON is referenced as `markers`.

```
markers.forEach(function(marker) {
  console.log(marker.name);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`markers` is an object that contain the array `marker`. You need to iterate `marker`

```js
var obj = {
  "markers": {
    "marker": [{
        "name": "john",
        "latitude": "53.4682282",
        "longitude": "-2.238547"
      },
      {
        "name": "david",
        "latitude": "53.4663409",
        "longitude": "-2.2328164"
      },
      {
        "name": "mathew",
        "latitude": "53.4668135",
        "longitude": "-2.2310998"
      }
    ]
  }
}

obj.markers.marker.forEach(m => console.log(m.name));
```

Comment: thanks, this helped me solve the problem. I will post the correct answer now

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
markers.marker.forEach(function(marker) {
  console.log(marker.name);
});
```

Comment: I have, my console gives me `TypeError: markers.marker is undefined`

Comment: Because you should firstly take you object and push property "markers" from it to the variable with name "markers".

Answer (score 0):

I needed to access the object inside the object. i.e.,

```
markers.markers.marker.forEach(function(marker) {
    console.log(marker.name);
});
```

Comment: I already post the answer which exactly solve your problem. You don't have to post an answer yourself. You can simply accept mine

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

'markers.marker.map((ma) => {
  console.log(ma.name);
});`